# IResource.setPersistentProperty on View

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse View and I want to set one of the users input values as a persistent property. I know that if I have one of the users projects (i.e. IProject), then I can do

```
project.setPersistentProperty(key,value);
```

However, for a View, I do not have the users project. How can I set a value / what is the correct way to set a persistent property in a persons workspace?

Comment: Persistent properties are always associated with an IResource. You could use a preference setting in an `IPreferenceStore` specific to your plugin.

Comment: @greg-449 would you recommend any good tutorial on doing this?

Comment: Preferences API is described [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set view properties for a certain workspace, you should use `IEclipsePreferences` with `instance` scope. This will return a `java.util.prefs.Preferences` object, which is a hierarchical preference store:

Quoting from excellent [Lars Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html) on the subject:

```
Preferences preferences = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("<Bundle-SymbolicName>");
Preferences sub1 = preferences.node("node1");
Preferences sub2 = preferences.node("node2");
sub1.put("h1", "Hello");
sub1.put("h2", "Hello again");
sub2.put("h1", "Moin");
try {
    // forces the application to save the preferences
    preferences.flush();
} catch (BackingStoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(where `<Bundle-SymbolicName>` is the symbolic name of your plugin, typically something like `org.some.organization.some.plugin`).

Comment: This did not fully work but it did lead me to the correct result. Thank you.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you feel it was helpful, or edit to reflect your changes to the sample code.